# Show $f(x)=\frac{1-2x}{\sqrt{x-x^2}}$ is an onto $f:(0,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, functions

In other words, need to show $\forall r \in \mathbb{R} (\exists x \in (0,1) [f(x)=r])$.
Suppose arbitrary $r \in \mathbb{R}$.
Tried finding such $x$ by letting
\begin{align*}
 r &= \frac{1-2x}{\sqrt{x-x^2}} \\
 r^2 &= \frac{1-4x+4x^2}{x-x^2}\\
 &= \frac{1-4(x-x^2)}{x-x^2} \\
 r^2 (x-x^2) &= 1-4(x-x^2) \\
 (r^2 +4)(x-x^2) &=1 \\
 (x-x^2) &= \frac{1}{r^2 +4} \\
 x^2 - x +\frac{1}{r^2 +4}  &= 0\\
 x &= \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a} \\
 x_1 &= \frac{1 + \sqrt{1-\frac{4}{r^2 + 4}}}{2} , \\
 x_2 &= \frac{1 - \sqrt{1-\frac{4}{r^2 + 4}}}{2} 
\end{align*}
The proof requirs $x \in (0,1)$, so need to show $0 < x < 1$. Since 
\begin{align*}
 0 \leq r^2 < \infty \\
 4 \leq r^2 + 4 < \infty \\
 0 < \frac{1}{ r^2 + 4 }  \leq \frac{1}{4}\\
 0 < \frac{4}{ r^2 + 4 }  \leq 1\\
 -1 \leq - \frac{4}{ r^2 + 4 } < 0\\
 0 \leq 1 - \frac{4}{ r^2 + 4 } < 1 \\
 0 \leq \sqrt{1 - \frac{4}{ r^2 + 4 }} < 1 \\
\end{align*}
For $x_1$,
\begin{align*}
 1 \leq 1 + \sqrt{1 - \frac{4}{ r^2 + 4 }} < 2 \\
 \frac{1}{2} \leq \frac{1 + \sqrt{1 - \frac{4}{ r^2 + 4 }}}{2} < 1\\
 \frac{1}{2} \leq x_1 < 1
\end{align*}
Similarly, for $x_2$,
\begin{align*}
 -1 < -\sqrt{1 - \frac{4}{ r^2 + 4 }} \leq 0 \\
 0 < 1  -\sqrt{1 - \frac{4}{ r^2 + 4 }} \leq 1 \\
 0 < \frac{1  -\sqrt{1 - \frac{4}{ r^2 + 4 }}}{2} \leq \frac{1}{2}\\
 0 < x_2 \leq \frac{1}{2}
\end{align*}
It looks like $x_1 \in [\frac{1}{2},1)$ should cover all $r \in \mathbb{R}$ which are negative, while $x_2 \in (0,\frac{1}{2}]$ should cover all $r \in \mathbb{R}$ which are positive.

This suggests choosing $x$ based on the polarity of the given $r \in \mathbb{R}$: upon plugging in $x_1$ into $r = \frac{1-2x}{\sqrt{x-x^2}}$, $r \in (-\infty, 0]$. Similarly, upon plugging in $x_2$, $r \in [0,+\infty)$. Let's try to show that these intervals for $r$ are correct.

\begin{align*}
 \frac{1}{2} \leq x_1 < 1 \\
 \frac{1}{4} \leq x_1^2 < 1 \\
 -1 < - x_1^2 \leq -\frac{1}{4} \\
 -1 + \frac{1}{2} < x_1 - x_1^2 < -\frac{1}{4} + 1 \\
 - \frac{1}{2}  < x_1 - x_1^2 <  \frac{3}{4}
\end{align*}
Weird. I cannot proceed by taking square root on all sides to obtain inequality for $\sqrt{ x_1 - x_1^2}$, let alone finding inequality for $r = \frac{1-2x_1}{\sqrt{x_1 - x_1^2}}$, which is suspected to be $-\infty < r \leq 0$.

Similar difficulty occurred when using $x_2$:
\begin{align*}
 0 < x_2 \leq \frac{1}{2} \\
 0 < x_2^2 \leq \frac{1}{4} \\
 - \frac{1}{4}  \leq - x_2^2 < 0 \\
 0 - \frac{1}{4} < x_2 - x_2^2 < \frac{1}{2} + 0 \\
 - \frac{1}{4} < x_2 - x_2^2 < \frac{1}{2}
\end{align*}

How to proceed to showing $r \in (-\infty, 0]$ if $x=x_1$, 
and $r \in [0,\infty)$ if $x=x_2$?

Comment: all what you wrote is correct. Your argument should stop when you bounded $x_2$ between zero and half.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $f$ is continuous in $(0,1)$, by the [Intermediate Value Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem), in order to show $f(0,1)=\mathbb{R}$ it suffices to verify that $$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{1-2x}{\sqrt{x-x^2}}=+\infty\quad \text{and}\quad\lim_{x\to 1^-}\frac{1-2x}{\sqrt{x-x^2}}=-\infty.$$

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this would help: If we mark $1-2x=t$ we get $$f(x) ={2t\over \sqrt{1-t^2}}$$

where $|t|<1$ so we can write $t= \sin \phi$ and we get $$f(x) = {2\sin \phi \over |\cos \phi|} =:g(\phi)$$

Notice that $g$ is odd and that for $\phi \in (0,\pi /2)$ we get $g(\phi) = 2\tan \phi $, so $f$ is surjective.

Answer (score 1):

If $x <1/2$, then $2x<1$, so $1-2x<0$. $x>1/2$ is similar. And note that if $0<x<1$ then $x^2<x$ so $x-x^2>0$.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple other answers here that give elegant responses to your title.

I'd like to address the point where you got stuck.

You wrote
\begin{align*}
 \frac{1}{2} \leq x_1 < 1\tag1 \\
 \frac{1}{4} \leq x_1^2 < 1 \tag2\\
 -1 < - x_1^2 \leq -\frac{1}{4} \tag3\\
 -1 + \frac{1}{2} < x_1 - x_1^2 < -\frac{1}{4} + 1 \tag4\\
 - \frac{1}{2}  < x_1 - x_1^2 <  \frac{3}{4}\tag5
\end{align*}

You must have obtained $(4)$ by adding $(1)$ and $(3)$.

If $(1)$ is true then $(4)$ holds (and so does $(5))$, but actually a stronger statement is true:

if $(1)$ is true then $0<x_1-x_1^2\le\dfrac14,$ because $x-x^2=\dfrac14-\left(x-\dfrac12\right)^2.$

From there, you should be able to get the result you want.

You got a weaker result because you added $(1)$ and $(3)$ as if $x_1$ and $x_1^2$ are independent variables;

you took the extreme values of $x_1$ and the extreme values of $x_1^2,$

rather than looking at the expression $x_1-x_1^2$ as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

Extended @Botond's answer:

i) If $x=x_1 \in [\frac{1}{2},1)$, then $r \in (-\infty, 0]$:
\begin{align*}
\begin{split}
\frac{1}{2} \leq x_1 &< 1 \\
1 \leq 2x_1 &< 2 \\
0 \leq 2x_1 - 1 &< 1 \quad \dots (1)
\end{split} \quad
\begin{split}
0< \frac{1}{2} \leq x_1 &< 1 \\
0< x_1^2 &< x_1 \\
-x_1 < -x_1^2 &< 0 \\
0 < x_1 - x_1^2 < x_1 &< 1 \\
0 < \sqrt{x_1 - x_1^2} &< 1 \\
1 < \frac{1}{\sqrt{x_1 - x_1^2}} &< +\infty\quad \dots (2)
\end{split}
\end{align*}
Multiplying the positive inequalities (1) and (2) together,
\begin{align*}
 0 \leq \frac{2x_1 - 1 }{\sqrt{x_1 - x_1^2}} &< +\infty \\
 -\infty< \frac{1- 2x_1 }{\sqrt{x_1 - x_1^2}} &\leq 0  \\
 \equiv r \in (-\infty, 0] &\quad \square
\end{align*}

ii) If $x_2 \in (0,\frac{1}{2}]$, then $r \in [0,+\infty)$:
\begin{align*}
\begin{split}
0 < x_2 &\leq \frac{1}{2} \\
0< 2x_2 &\leq 1 \\
-1 \leq -2x_2 &< 0 \\
0 \leq 1-2x_2 &< 1 \quad \dots (3)
\end{split} \quad
\begin{split}
0 < x_2 &\leq \frac{1}{2} < 1\\
\text{Similar to (2),} \\
1 < \frac{1}{\sqrt{x_2 - x_2^2}} &< +\infty \quad \dots (4)
\end{split}
\end{align*}
Multiplying the positive inequalities (3) and (4) together,
\begin{align*}
 0 \leq \frac{1-2x_2}{\sqrt{x_2 - x_2^2}}  &< +\infty \\
 \equiv r \in [0,+\infty) &\quad \square
\end{align*}